# How to get integer from division

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to extract specific integer part from division. I figured out a simple function that return what i need. For example, if i got 40, i need at integer that left after division to 12. So, if i got 40 i need 3 (3*36+4 = 40).

I tried  `NSLog(@"-40 modulo %i", (div(42, 12)));` and it output me 3.

However, trying to assign an NSInteger var to this output an error:

```
_yearsModif = div(self.counterForYearsModif, 12);
```

It output red warning -  `Assigning to 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') from incompatible type 'div_t'`

How to assign result to simple integer variable? Thanks.

Comment: Why so complicated? If your math is with integers you could use modulo operator `%`? Or just calculate it out of division: `int x = 40; int div = x / 12; int result = x - (div * 12);`. Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide. Integer division already does what you want:

```
NSInteger counterForYearsModif = 40;
NSInteger _yearsModif = counterForYearsModif / 12;
NSLog(@"%ld", _yearsModif); // 3
```

Comment: what about rounding? What if i got 2.9 and it evaluate to 3? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, certainly. But it isn't what you asked.